# Disabling caret browsing in Firefox source view

Tags: firefox, caret

In the contemporary versions of Firefox, when opening the source-code view of a webpage, the source window is always in "caret-browsing" mode, i.e. when scrolling with the arrow keys you have to wait for a text cursor to jump all the way to the top or bottom of the window for the window to scroll.  This is very annoying and I want to disable caret browsing for easy scrolling, but there does not appear to be any option for this.  Is it possible to disable the caret browsing in the source window, or did Mozilla make this a hard-coded setting?

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround: access the configurations (about:config) and go to view_source.editor.external, double click to set to true; then modify view_source.editor.path to a text editor (mine is at c:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe). This will let you see (and navigate in) the source in an application of your choosing.

Comment: That's one potentially good approach, but is it confirmed that there is no way to disable caret browsing in the native source window?  Would the feature have to be requested in Bugzilla?

Comment: Sorry, don't know...but a search showed that it was considered a bug in an earlier version when the caret didn't appear. It seems that they like it that way :/